# Unable to debug with blazor (missing file://)

Tags: debugging, blazor

When I open the debugger and go to sources I'm not able to see the (file://) node.
Why am I not seeing this and how can I get it ?
What I have:
[image: Screenshot off the sources tab]
What I need:
[image: What I want to see]

Comment: The `file://` instructs a web browser to access the local file that follows the prefix, it sounds like the IIS debug web server isn't set up properly.

Comment: How do i setup the web server ?

Comment: i did found out that if I use my laptop it works but on desktop it doesn't